# php remote form post script

Tags: php, curl

How to create error reporting for this script below to make sure its working
and is there anything wrong with it

```
<?php

$username="username here";
$password="password here";
$url="url here";
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$postdata = $username . $password . $url;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl_exec()` returns `FALSE` on failure.  Check for it's success before echoing your `$result`.  On failure, call [`curl_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.curl-error.php) to see the most recent error message returned.

```
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
if ($result) {
  // Success.
  echo $result;
}
else {
  // something went wrong.
  echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
exit();
```